# Transparently bridge network over serial link

Tags: networking, ip, serial-port, bridge, pppd

I have two Linux devices - for simplicity let's call them Raspberry Pi's - in a box that I want to connect to a network with a singe Ethernet link.

Both of them need to be accessible, individually, on the network. I can join one to the other through a serial port very easily.

It looks like `pppd` or `slip` may be the answer, however all the examples I've seen so far use fixed configurations which is no use to me - **both** boards need to be able to take on **any** IP address either via DHCP or manually configured, independent of configuration on the other.

This feels like it should be fairly easy to accomplish with Linux but either I'm not finding the right info or I'm using the wrong terms while searching.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think you want PPP  slip is simpler, however they work like a gateway device, to a separate network, so you need to setup a static route on the device which is connected to the ethernet. Search for dynamic IP address assignment PPP protocol

Answer (score 1):

You could rig up something with [socat](/questions/tagged/socat) and [tap](/questions/tagged/tap)s and bridges.

On both ends of the serial port you'd use a variation of this

```
socat TUN,tun-type=tap,iff-up /dev/ttyS0
```

, and you get a TAP ethernet device on both ends of the serial connection.

[socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) has [a bunch of options for the TAP-device](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#OPTION_TUN_DEVICE) and for [the serial port](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#GROUP_TERMIOS).

You may need to select optimal serial port speeds manually, and you will have to do bridging, and other network integration of the TAP-devices on both ends.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of a chicken/egg problem: to establish a PPP/SLIP connection, you'll need the IP parameters, but the serial-connected device has no way of making DHCP requests until the PPP/SLIP connection is up. PPP has its own method for passing configuration information from the PPP server to the client, but SLIP may need pre-existing configuration information at both ends of the serial link if I remember correctly.

As far as I can see, you have two alternatives:

A.) Use fixed private IPs to set up the PPP/SLIP link, and if a link is connected, have the Ethernet-connected device configure a second IP address for itself (either by running a second instance of a DHCP client or from manual configuration) and use NAT to redirect the traffic of the second IP address to the fixed address used on the serial link.

In this method, the serial-connected client won't necessarily know its real IP address, which may be problematic if you need to use a network protocol that is not NAT-friendly. On the other hand, the second address doesn't have to be reserved until the connection is actually established.

B.) Have the Ethernet-connected device always be configured with two IP addresses Ethernet-side (e.g. run two instances of a DHCP client if using DHCP), and once the second address is known, use it to configure the server-side of the serial link. If using `pppd`, use its `proxyarp` option. If using SLIP, configure proxy ARP in some other way (e.g. `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/proxy_arp`).

This method will have the Ethernet-connected device always reserve two IP addresses if configured to be ready for serial connections, but will allow the serial-connected device to actually hold the IP address it will be reachable as.

With both methods, the majority of the network configuration for the serial-connected device must happen at the Ethernet-connected device.